# Doctrine Query: Result creates array with index offset

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a DQL string:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,
       b,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(c)
           FROM ..\Entity\EntityC c
           WHERE c.b = b
       ),
       (
           SELECT MAX(c2.date)
           FROM ..\Entity\EntityC c2
           WHERE c2.b = b
       )
 FROM ..\Entity\EntityA a
 JOIN a.b b
 ...
```

I want to retrieve some a's, the count of c's that relate to a.b, and the date of the latest c.
My code DOES generate the results I want, but the resulting arrays have an offset in their indices:

```
array(size = [rows])
  0 => array (size = 3)
         0 => Entity(a)
         1 => int(COUNT(c))
         3 => date(MAX(c2.date))
  1 => array (size = 3)
         0 => Entity(a)
         1 => int(COUNT(c))
         3 => date(MAX(c2.date))
  ...
```

Why does this offset happen, and is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is related to this
"If you fetch multiple entities that are listed in the FROM clause then the hydration will return the rows iterating the different top-level entities." (From http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#fetching-multiple-from-entities )

```
$dql = "SELECT u, g FROM User u, Group g";

array
     [0] => Object (User)
     [1] => Object (Group)
     [2] => Object (User)
     [3] => Object (Group)
```

Could you verify doing a dump on the next row?
Best regards

Comment: I already assumed that the problem lies within hydration, but your suggestion goes another way than my problem. I will edit my question for details.